# Visual Studio Code Ionic Project - Android Build Error readConfiguration is not a function

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic-framework

**When i try to build Android APK using the below command:**
ionic cordova build --release android --stacktrace

**I got the below error:**
[error] TypeError: readConfiguration is not a function
at readTsconfig (D:\subha\CTC\Ionicapp_CTC\node_modules@angular-devkit\build-angular\src\utils\read-    tsconfig.js:49:26)
at async configureI18nBuild (D:\subha\CTC\Ionicapp_CTC\node_modules@angular-devkit\build-   angular\src\utils\i18n-options.js:125:22)
at async generateI18nBrowserWebpackConfigFromContext (D:\subha\CTC\Ionicapp_CTC\node_modules@angular-  devkit\build-angular\src\utils\webpack-browser-config.js:66:36)
at async initialize (D:\subha\CTC\Ionicapp_CTC\node_modules@angular-devkit\build-   angular\src\builders\browser\index.js:67:62)
at async D:\subha\CTC\Ionicapp_CTC\node_modules@angular-devkit\build-  angular\src\builders\browser\index.js:98:32

**Ionic Environment Info:**
Ionic CLI : 5.4.16 (C:\Users\sofis\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic)
Ionic Framework : @ionic/angular 4.11.13
@angular-devkit/build-angular : 16.1.8
@angular-devkit/schematics : 7.3.9
@angular/cli : 15.2.9
@ionic/angular-toolkit : 1.5.1

**Cordova:**

```
Cordova CLI : 10.0.0
Cordova Platforms : 6.0.0, android 8.0.0, browser, ios 5.1.1
Cordova Plugins : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.2.0, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 4.1.3, (and 13    other plugins)
```

Utility:

```
cordova-res : 0.15.1
native-run : 0.2.7
```

System:

```
NodeJS : v14.20.0 (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe)
npm : 6.14.17
OS : Windows 10
```

Comment: Hello there. Did you try to clean and rebuild your project? 
`ionic cordova platform rm android`
`ionic cordova platform add android`
`ionic cordova build --release android --stacktrace`